# Xcode 7.2 <unknown>:0: error: unexpected input file: (path to file)/Main.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm working with Xcode 7.2 on an iOS app in swift when suddenly got the following error at build time (replaced User and app name by variables):

```
<unknown>:0: error: unexpected input file: /Users/($User)/Code/($appname)/($appname)/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
```

I was trying to add some label on a view and update it via some code, it was in a trial and error way...

while searching on the web for solutions, I found strange that a right-click on

"Main.storyboard -> Open As" proposes:

- source code
- ASCII property list
- Hex
- Quick Look

but does not propose "Interface builder - Storyboard" as some solutions pointed out

Any help are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your project cannot able to find `Main.StoryBoard`.

You may just look in `/projectName/projectName/Base.lproj`. The storyboard is there. You can drag it into Xcode and its as good as new.

Comment: Thank you very much, this did solve the issue. However this is strange as the file was already in the mentioned folder, and the content was readable via Xcode. Just deleted the reference and reimported and worked.

Comment: Answer accepted and upvoted, but as new user not public visible.